# Infiniti semplici utilizzati come infiniti passivi: è possibile?

Tags: verbs, infinitive

Buona sera,

Ho un dubbio grammaticale sulla parte in grassetto in questa  frase tratta da *Il fu Mattia Pascal*:

> Eppure, conoscendo Papiano, avrebbe dovuto nascermi il sospetto che, se egli si rassegnava a lasciarmi accanto Adriana e, contrariamente a’ miei timori, **non ci faceva mai disturbare dallo spirito di Max**, anzi pareva che ci favorisse e ci proteggesse, doveva aver fatto qualche altra pensata.

Il verbo *disturbare* è evidentamente preso come un infinito passivo, con *noi* come il soggetto grammaticale indotto da *fare* (cioè *farci fare qualche cosa*) e con *lo spirito di Max* come l'agente semantico, cioè l'ente che disturba. Ma, se il latino aveva gli infiniti passivi per i verbi, l'italiano sembra di utilizzare invece le costruzioni con il verbo *essere*: *essere disturbati* ecc. Quindi il dubbio: nella realtà, come è composta questa parte? Il significato è chiarissimo, ma la grammatica non lo è. Grazie!

Comment: Il soggetto è “egli”, cioè Papiano.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Capisco il senso della domanda, ma mi sembra che i grammatici italiani non interpretino questo tipo di infinito come una sorta di passivo. La questione riguarda più in generale le costruzioni con i verbi “causativi” *fare* e *lasciare*. Dice *Italiano* di Serianni:

> Il costrutto del tipo «far fare qualcosa a / da qualcuno» presenta una specie di cooperazione tra i due soggetti, quello grammaticale del verbo causativo e quello logico dell'infinito, giacché il primo mette in moto l'azione del secondo: «io [soggetto grammaticale] faccio che *x* [soggetto logico] faccia qualcosa» → «io faccio fare qualcosa a / da _x_». ... Il soggetto logico è rappresentato da un complemento indiretto introdotto da *a* o *da* (con diverse sfumature semantiche: «lo farò vedere *al* dottor Rossi», «lo farò vedere *dal* dottor Rossi»; nel sistema pronominale: *gli*, *le* / *da lui*, *da lei*, ecc.

E rimanda per maggiori approfondimenti a Gunver Skytte, “La sintassi dell'infinito in italiano moderno”, *Revue Romane*, num. supplem. 27, 1983 (in particolare, vol. I, pp. 57-75), che non ho avuto modo di consultare.